# Javascript - Check if a certain array key exists using regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have an associative array and I would like to search in the array if there is one key that ends with the letter "r".
It works when I use the "in" javascript keyword for a static string but not dynamically, using regex.

Comment: Could you include your code please?

Comment: You will have to iterate over all the properties in the object and test each one.

Comment: How exactly should regex search through your array anyhow? Regex doesn't work like that, you have to evaluate strings with regex. Regex does not work on general data, just on strings.

Comment: "for a static string but not dynamically, using regex." what does that mean? what is a static string?

Comment: Please read how to ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Why have you decided that a regex is the way to go? What benefit do you see it providing? Is the object originating from JSON data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Object.keys(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) gets the keys of the object as an array. Because it's an array you can then use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to select the keys that you're interested in:

```
keysEndingWithR =
  Object
    .keys(obj)
    .filter(function (key) {
      return /r$/.test(key);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the properties of the object and for each one test if your expression matches. Return the property name if it does.

```
function getMatchingPropertyName(expression, object)
    for (var property in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (expression.test(property)) {
                return property
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

or if you want all matching property names:

```
function getMatchingPropertyNames(expression, object)
    var result = [];
    for (var property in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (expression.test(property)) {
                result.push(property);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if a dirty quick test is enough you could try something like:

```
/r":/.test(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

besides that zzzzBov functional solution can also be used with Array.prototype.some()

```
Object.keys(obj).some(function (key) {
  return /r$/.test(key);
});
```

Comment: I just threw up in my mouth a little. Parsing JSON with regex...? And it's not even JSON to begin with!

Comment: he said associative array so I assume a normal object like obj = { a: 1, b: 2, r: 3 }; -  what's wrong about parsing such an obj to a string and using regex test on it, if he just wants to check if there is one key that ends with the letter "r" ?

Comment: It being inefficient is beside the point. So is whether `JSON.stringify` is required to not put whitespace between names and colons. But this will give a false positive if `obj = { a: { r: 0 } }`.

Comment: well, but he asked for using regex - of course you dont need regex at all:
Object.keys(obj).some(function (key) {
  return key.slice(-1) === 'r';
});
He did not specify how the associative array looks like and if it contains nested stuff, so it's just a vague answer, e.g. nested elements need to be intercepted:
Object.keys(obj).some(function (key) {
  if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
    return Object.keys(obj[key]).some(function (subkey) {
      return subkey.slice(-1) === 'r';
    });
  } else {
    return key.slice(-1) === 'r';
  }
});

Comment: I assume OP meant to use regex on each key.

Comment: anyways you're right if the main object contains objects you cant use the dirty thing :)